# How to get the stackoverflow topic ID to display prominently?

Tags: firefox-addon, stackexchange

For many of the questions I find helpful on SO, I note the topic (question) ID in my notebook.  The question ID (a number) is in the URL, but locating it in the browser address bar is error-prone if not inconvenient.  How can I go about writing an add-on for Firefox that will somehow display the question ID prominently (in large font)?

Note: I am asking this question here because SO is the stackexchange site I use most frequently.

Comment: "Note: I am asking this question here because SO is the stackexchange site I use most frequently." That's... not how it's done.

Comment: You track stackoverflow questions in a notebook?  Why not use the built in Favorites function..

Comment: I use my notebook for other things as well, not just SO question numbers - e.g. examples from books, my own findings, etc.

Comment: @Sabuncu Boltclock means you should pick the site you ask on based on whether your question is on topic there.

Comment: @Kevin: I understand, but my question applies to all stackexchange sites, and when I went to stackexchange.com, I did not see a forum relating to its API.  Do you know where it is?  Thanks.

Comment: @Sabuncu This question isn't all that bad as far as being on topic, since it's asking about how to program. The way you decided where to post it is what's at issue. But since you asked, there is [meta].

Comment: Great, thanks so much.  The name "meta" makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for an add-on just to get the question ID. The following bookmarklet shows the question ID of the current question.

```
javascript:alert(StackExchange.question.getQuestionId());
```

I found this as follows:

1. Show source (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> in Firefox)
2. Search for *17010194`, enable *Highlight all*
3. Observe a line containing:

   > StackExchange.question.init({votesCast:[],canViewVoteCounts:true,totalCommentCount:4,shownCommentCount:4,highlightColor:'#F4A83D',backgroundColor:'#FFF',questionId:17010194});
4. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to open the Web console.
5. Enter `StackExchange.question` and click on the result to inspect the object properties:
   [image: inspect StackExchange.question]
6. Guess that `StackExchange.question.getQuestionId` is a function returning the question ID (type it in the Web Console).
7. On observation that this works, put it in `javascript:alert(...)` and post an answer.

Comment: @Sabuncu if you are asking this on SO, I assume you know how to add a bookmarklet. If not, look on http://superuser.com/ or google it.

Comment: You are absolutely right! ;-)  Did look it up on superuser.com, installed it, works like a charm.  Excellent answer, thank you.

Comment: Just curious, and I am not familiar w/ JavaScript or AJAX much: where is StackExchange.question.getQuestionId() defined?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Sabuncu Please see the updated answer on how I determined this function. Sorry, if you want to know the definition, you have to learn a bit more about Javascript and its tools. Hint: use Firebug or the Web developer tools of Chrome.

Comment: Simply amazing!  [I have Firebug installed, and have used it in the past, but there is the intimidation factor, so... ] My question was: Is this function in a .js file, or is it on the server side?

Comment: @Sabuncu Javascript is always client-side, so yes it is likely in a ".js" file. Calling the function does not involve a server-request ("AJAX" if you like to name it like that) as the ID was already provided when the page was loaded.

Comment: THANK YOU!  This has been so helpful, even beyond the original question.